# How to get first and last row in Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` which binds data on page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
    { 
        BindCustomerData(); 
    }
}
```

I would like to display different buttons depending on the criteria. For simplicity

If its the first gridview row then display "First Record"

If its the last gridview row then display "Last Record"

Any other row "Middle Record"

All buttons start with `Visible = False` on the markup.

In my `RowDataBound` event i have

```
protected void gvCusts_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int lastIndex = gvCusts.Rows.Count -1;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button buttonFirst = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("buttonFirst");
        Button buttonMiddle = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("buttonMiddle");
        Button buttonLast = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("buttonLast");

        // Customer Records found
        if (c.Id > 0)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
            {
                // First row so display first button only
                buttonFirst.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowIndex >= 1 && e.Row.RowIndex <= lastIndex)
            {
                // Not the first row and not the last row so display the middle button only
                buttonMiddle.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowIndex == lastIndex)
            {
                // Last row, so display the last button only.
                buttonLast.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is i cant find a proper way to get the middle and last rows and have buttons showing at the wrong stages.
I then made the int `lastIndex = gvCusts.Rows.Count -1;` line of code `static` and still not getting the correct results.

I've read a number of articles so obviously i'm missing something somewhere but not sure what?

Comment: lastIndex calculation is wrong, it sholuld be from your datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare a static variable rowCount in your class.

```
int rowCount=0;
```

2. In your BindCustomerData() method, pass the number of rows to rowCount variable.

```
rowCount= YourDataTable.Rows.Count-1;
```

3. Now, get first and last index from rowCount Variable.

```
protected void gvCusts_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int lastIndex = rowCount;//rowCount has the last index

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button buttonFirst = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("buttonFirst");
        Button buttonMiddle = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("buttonMiddle");
        Button buttonLast = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("buttonLast");

        // Customer Records found
        if (c.Id > 0)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
            {
                // First row so display first button only
                buttonFirst.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowIndex >= 1 && e.Row.RowIndex < rowCount)
            {
                // Not the first row and not the last row so display the middle button only
                buttonMiddle.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowIndex == rowCount)
            {
                // Last row, so display the last button only.
                buttonLast.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - i just realised i was setting the total count after DataBind() and should have had it before.